# Cassandra on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra, cql

I followed this http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/install/installAMI.html and then I try to use this ruby gem (https://github.com/iconara/cql-rb) to connect to my EC2 instance but i get the following error:

> irb(main):013:0> Cql::Client.connect(host: 'PUBLIC_DNS', port: 9160)
>   Cql::Io::ConnectionError: end of file reached     from
>   /Users/damien/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cql-rb-2.0.0.pre0/lib/cql/client/synchronous_client.rb:32:in
>   `connect'     from
>   /Users/damien/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cql-rb-2.0.0.pre0/lib/cql/client.rb:118:in`
>   connect'     from (irb):13   from
>   /Users/damien/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/bin/irb:12:in `'

If I SSH to the box and use cqlsh to connect to localhost it works fine.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the native_transport_port which defaults to 9042, not the rpc_port which defaults to 9160. However, both ports are configurable inside of cassandra.yaml after a Cassandra server restart.